# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los componentes de una forma en orden en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, lista

Verán, lo que quiero es capturar los datos de varios Textbox y guardarlos en una lista. Ya he logrado obtener el contenido de cada textbox pero por alguna razón, siempre me devuelve los valores desde el último, hasta el primero. Intenté usar tags para ordenarlo pero en esos casos solo me guarda un valor. Este es mi código:

```
    int posicion = 0;
    int etiqueta;
    List<string> lista = new List<string>();
    
    public void Insertar_Datos(Form forma)
    {
        foreach (Control x in forma.Controls)
        {
            //posicion = Convert.ToInt32(x.Tag) - 1;
            etiqueta = Convert.ToInt32(x.Tag) -1;
            if (x is TextBox)
            {
                if (x.Tag != null)                       
                {
                    if (x.Tag.ToString() != "" && etiqueta == posicion)          
                    {
                        if (x.Text != "")
                        {
                            //lista[posicion] = x.Text;
                            lista.Add(x.Text);
                            MessageBox.Show(x.Text);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Una pregunta, no tendrás los textboxes en algun otro control de tipo contenedor? Si es así tendrás que recorrer los controles de forma recursiva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero deberás recuperar todos los controles de tipo `TextBox` inclusive dentro de aquellos que sean contenedores de otros controles. Para ello puedes usar este código

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control,Type type)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl,type))
                              .Concat(controls)
                              .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
}
```

Luego aplicando lo indicado en la respuesta de Carlos puedes hacer.

```
var textboxesOrdenados = GetAll(this,typeof(TextBox))
                              .Where(textBox => textBox.Text != "")
                              .OrderBy(textBox => int.Parse(textBox.Tag));

// Los que queden son los deseados
foreach (var textBox in textBoxesOrdenados)
{
    lista.Add(textBox.Text);
    MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Una duda... ¿Cómo podría hacer para que también me ordenara los combobox y los datetimepicker? Es que también los utilizo para capturar los datos que van en la lista.

Comment: Crea tres listas, una con textboxes, otra con el combo y otra con el datetimepicker. La clase `Control` tiene como propiedad el tag con lo que puedes "fusionar" esas tres listas en una List<Control> y luego aplicar linq

Answer (score 1):

Si los Tags son los que te indican el orden entonces podrías hacer lo siguiente dentro de `Insertar_Datos`

```
// Podrías utilizar linq sobre la lista de Controles del formulario:
// Filtras los controles que sean TextBoxes y que su Tag pueda convertirse a entero
// A cada uno lo conviertes a TextBox
// Quitas aquellos cuya propiedad Text sea igual a ""
// Los TextBoxes que queden, los ordenas por su Tag

var textBoxesOrdenados = 
    forma.Controls.Where(c => c is TextBox && int.TryParse(c.Tag?.ToString(), out int _))
              .Select(c=>(TextBox)c)
              .Where(textBox => textBox.Text != "")
              .OrderBy(textBox => int.Parse(textBox.Tag));

// Los que queden son los deseados
foreach (var textBox in textBoxesOrdenados)
{
    lista.Add(textBox.Text);
    MessageBox.Show(textBox.Text);
}
```

Comment: También puedes utilizar `forma.Controls.OfType<TextBox>`